# android manifest build number

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

I was wondering if it is possible to have Eclipse automatically increment the build version number inside of the `Manifest` each time that I either build or run an Android app.

Has anyone ever done something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think Eclipse itself can do it, but I would imagine you could write a script that parses the manifest file and updates the number. You could set that up as a pre-build step, so every time Eclipse compiles your code, it changes the number.

My only concern with that would be that you could reach pretty big numbers, depending on how iterative your development process is. Also, this puts you at risk at forgetting to update the version string, and the users will be prompted to upgrade from version 1.0 to version 1.0.

Comment: No reason the script couldn't update the version string too :) Do you know how to get Eclipse to run a script? I was planning on avoiding large numbers by setting it up only to run when I push it to a device/emulator.

Comment: It sure could, but I don't know if you prefer to be in control of the version string, since that is exposed to the user. You can set up build steps in the project settings. I don't have it in front of me right now, but there are basically build steps a) when building, b) when cleaning the project, and you can add any number of steps. Each step can be an arbitrary command that is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here my **almost generic** Java app to update **version code and version name**

Almost generic, because file parsing is not 100% guarantee (works fine with well formatted xml manifest and should be OK in most case)

Choices/prerequisite:

- versionName is supposed to be **major.minor.point** (as advised by Android doc)
- versionName can be preserved, reset to 1.0.0, or incremented (one single part of it and trailing part(s) is/are set to 0)
- versionCode will be replaced by **Unix Time**

Code:

```
package com.mycompany.tools;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class IncrementVersion
{
    enum INCREMENT
    {
        MAJOR, // increment 1rst component of version Code (i.e. 'major') add trailing '.0.0'
        MINOR, // preserve major, increment 2nd component of version Code (i.e. 'minor'), add trailing '.0'
        POINT, // preserver major, minor, increment 3rd component of version Code (i.e. 'point')
        NONE, // do not change versionName, only change version code (to current Unix times)
        RESET // RESET -> reset verseionNAme to 1.0.0
    }


    // update this to select which version name part to update
    static final INCREMENT increment = INCREMENT.NONE;

    static final String projectName = "com.mycompany.myproject";
    // OR static final String projectName = "com.mycompany"; -> match all my projects :-)

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File directory = new File("");

        for (File projectDirecotry : directory.listFiles())
        {
            if (projectDirecotry.getName().startsWith(projectName))
            {
                exec(projectDirecotry);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void exec(File projectDirectory)
    {
        File androidManifestFile = new File(projectDirectory, "AndroidManifest.xml");
        if (androidManifestFile.exists())
        {
            writeFile(androidManifestFile, readFile(androidManifestFile));
        }
    }

    private static void writeFile(File androidManifestFile, String newContent)
    {
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try
        {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(androidManifestFile));
            bw.write(newContent);
        } catch (Throwable th)
        {
            th.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            if (bw != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    bw.close();
                } catch (Throwable th)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static String readFile(File androidManifestFile)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(androidManifestFile));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(parse(line)).append('\n');
                //              System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Throwable th)
        {
            th.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            if (br != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    br.close();
                } catch (Throwable th)
                {
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    //  public static final DateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm", Locale.ROOT);

    public static long getUnixTime()
    {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
    }

    private static String parse(String line)
    {
        {
            //      android:versionCode="1"
            // use 201408221404 instead
            String versionCodePrefix = "android:versionCode=\"";

            int indexOfVersionCodePrefix = line.indexOf(versionCodePrefix);
            if (indexOfVersionCodePrefix != -1)
            {
                indexOfVersionCodePrefix += versionCodePrefix.length();
                versionCodePrefix = line.substring(0, indexOfVersionCodePrefix);
                String versionCode = line.substring(indexOfVersionCodePrefix, line.length());

                int indexOfVersionCodeSuffix = versionCode.indexOf('"');
                if (indexOfVersionCodeSuffix != -1)
                {
                    String versionCodeSuffix = versionCode.substring(indexOfVersionCodeSuffix);
                    //                  versionCode = versionCode.substring(0, indexOfVersionCodeSuffix);
                    //                  return versionCodePrefix + (Integer.parseInt(versionCode) + 1) + versionCodeSuffix;
                    // 1409302337
                    return versionCodePrefix + getUnixTime() + versionCodeSuffix;
                }
            }
        }

        {
            if (increment != INCREMENT.NONE)
            {
                //      android:versionName="1.0.0" >

                String versionNamePrefix = "android:versionName=\"";

                int indexOfVersionNamePrefix = line.indexOf(versionNamePrefix);
                if (indexOfVersionNamePrefix != -1)
                {
                    indexOfVersionNamePrefix += versionNamePrefix.length();
                    versionNamePrefix = line.substring(0, indexOfVersionNamePrefix);
                    String versionName = line.substring(indexOfVersionNamePrefix, line.length());

                    int indexOfVersionCodeSuffix = versionName.indexOf('"');
                    if (indexOfVersionCodeSuffix != -1)
                    {
                        String versionNameSuffix = versionName.substring(indexOfVersionCodeSuffix);
                        versionName = versionName.substring(0, indexOfVersionCodeSuffix);

                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\.])*\\.([^\\.])*\\.([^\\.])*");
                        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(versionName);
                        if (m.matches())
                        {
                            int major = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
                            int minor = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
                            int point = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));

                            switch (increment)
                            {
                            case MAJOR:
                                major += 1;
                                minor = 0;
                                point = 0;
                                break;
                            case MINOR:
                                minor += 1;
                                point = 0;
                                break;
                            case POINT:
                                point += 1;
                                break;
                            case RESET:
                                major = 1;
                                minor = 0;
                                point = 0;
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                            }

                            return versionNamePrefix + major + '.' + minor + '.' + point + versionNameSuffix;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return line;
    }
}
```