# Android Manifest Questions

Tags: android, manifest

When I upload my APK to Google Play console if I later need to change my manifest to disallow something can I do it?

Example:
I want to have my application only allow devices with cameras. If I later decide they no longer need a camera I update the manifest to allow this?

Meaning are manifest changes "At will"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can change the manifest at will but it obviously won't affect your uploaded apk. You have to build and upload a new version of your app so that the users can install/update the new version.
Important is to increment your app's version code before building and uploading, because you can not provide two apks having the same.

For further information on how to provide an update via Google Play, check this link:

http://support.andromo.com/kb/distributing/how-to-update-your-app-in-google-play

Comment: For what it's worth, my way to increment app version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673452/android-manifest-build-number/26377745#26377745 ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can change permissions, minimum sdk api, maximum sdk api, themes, intent, etc...

Clarification: I never thought you can magically change your APK without uploading it.  I thought that was assumed.  My mistake.

Comment: So once I post the APK the permissions are not set, and can be allowed or disallowed at any time? --- type of Trial and Error?

Comment: No. Once you compile and build your APK, the AndroidManifest cannot be changed on Google Play. You would have to build and upload a new APK.